# Using Dictionary<string, string> in EF Core LINQ: .Any could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Is there some trick to using `.Any` within a LINQ query within EF Core?

`f.Filters` is of the type `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
var items = await _dbContext.MyItems
                .Where(f => f.ID == 1)
                .Where(f => f.Filters.Keys.Any( k => k == "My Key"))
                .ToListAsync();
```

When I run this, I get :

The LINQ expression

```
DbSet<MyItems>()
 .Where(f => f.ID == 1)
 .Where(f => f.Filters.Keys
 .Any())
```

could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
>   AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I tried adding `AsEnumerable` as the docs state, but that doesn't seem to make a difference:

IE:

```
var items = await _dbContext.MyItems
                .Where(f => f.ID == 1)
                .Where(f => f.Filters.Keys.AsEnumerable().Any( k => k == "My Key"))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Looks like EF do not know how to translate dictionary property and it's keys to SQL. Is `f.Filters` is mapped by EF?

Comment: Yes, it is mapped correctly. It's stored as string in the database but I have a converter setup in the OnModelCreate to go from string > DIction<string, string>. It works just fine if I just remove that where clause from the EF Query and then do it after the fact. Just can't do it within the actual database query for some reason.

Comment: I would bet it is not `Any` it is `f.Filters.Keys` what causing problems. I'm afraid you will need to write custom [IMethodCallTranslator](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/custom-functions-using-imethodcalltranslator-in-2-1/) or even go deeper. Also if you decide to go this way i think better option would be to call `f.Filters.ContainsKey("My Key")`

Comment: Thanks. Yea, I tried ContainsKey originaly but that gave me the same issue

Comment: I would expect that =) Again -  more hacking into EF core internals is the only option for you to support such query. Or use [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1), which, i think, would be much easier option.

Comment: FYI I think it meant for you to put the `AsEnumerable` between the 2 `Where` calls and not inside of the second one.  And from the sounds of it you'd need some type of `Like` query to do that in SQL anyway probably as `f => f.Filter.Contains("My Key")` or some such.

Comment: You can't use converted properties in `Where` clauses. The conversion is client-side and EF doesn't translate the conversions into SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold That seems like the answer to this question. I am working with a converted property so it makes sense why I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use converted properties in `Where` clauses. The conversion is
> client-side and EF doesn't translate the conversions into SQL.
>
>  - **@Gert Arnold** in question comments

After calling `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, `.ToDictionaryAsync()` or `.ToArrayAsync()` etc, you can utilize conversion properties at any time. This is because calling any of the `.To` or similar functions executes the database query, shifting any subsequent LINQ operations to the client side instead of the server side.

Good rule of thumb; if using LINQ and there is function ending in `Async`, those calls and their non-async counterparts will execute the database query.

Comment: Old question, posting this answer so anybody else with a similar question doesn't have to dig through the comments.